# Mysql, finding values, with most

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a couple of tables. I'm looking for the value/person that has most records in the table. If there are more that have just as much then all of them should be selected.

That thing is i have 2 tables, so i should select information from the person with most values. and how many.

My testing looks like this

```
select*, tbl1.Value, count (*) as atn
from Tbl1, Tbl1
group by Value
order by antall Atn
```

```
select*
from Tbl1 left outer join tbl2
on tbl1.value= tbl2.value;
```

Lets say this is the result.

Meaning that

```
Value-Value-value-atn
--------------------
22    name  name  2
--------------------
```

this person out of 10 people had most records in the table, and Name value comes from another table.

Comment: At the very least provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: update your question and a proper data sample  .. too

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Value,
       atn
FROM ( SELECT Value,
              COUNT( * ) AS atn
       FROM Tbl1
       GROUP BY Value
     ) AS atnFinder
GROUP BY Value,
         atn
HAVING atn = MAX( atn )
ORDER BY Value;
```

This statement uses the subquery `atnFinder` to first determine the count of records corresponding to each `Value`.  The results of this subquery are then grouped by each returned field, making each returned record its own group as well.  It then uses the `HAVING` clause to return each group / record having the maximum value of `atn`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.